# Can't install Ubuntu on AMD Athlon XP 2100 with MSI graphics card

Tags: installation, 12.04

I have tried installing Ubuntu several times and it always ends in abject failure. Persistent idiot that I am, I'm trying again.

This is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it starts with the image on the monitor dancing about and finishes with it looking like an elderly television set with part of the picture from one side appearing at the other and the happy dancing lines. It complements this funky image with the legend "Installation Failed".

Is it time for me to give up and just use Windows or is there something simple I could do to make it better. Please don't offer suggestions like "go to this kernel or that", because I've never got that far and kernels are just things other people have.

Apart from that I'd be very grateful for any help or advice.

Edit to expand

I have now tried using an alternative and got to this,

"Failed to install the base system
The base system installation into /target / failed.
Check /var / log / syslog or see virtual console 4 for the details.

How would I do that?

I should just give that nice man Gates my money shouldn't I? This Linux thing is a big practical joke isn't it like a Rick Roll only more frustrating?

Comment: Pls include ur system properties.Try to select "install ubuntu" instead of selecting "try ubuntu" and followed by an install.I think u r running on a low RAM system.

Comment: If I could get past the "installation failed" bit I would. It's an AMD Athlon XP 2100 processor and an MSI graphics card if that's any help.

Comment: I am trying to "install Ubuntu", not "try ubuntu"

Comment: I don't know much about graphic cards, but it sounds like a graphic card problem to me, more than a RAM problem. How much RAM do you have? What graphics card exactly?

Comment: Thank you Agmenor for editing my title. It makes more sense now.

Comment: I also wonder how to check that install log. It's really reatarded.

Answer (score 1):

I have literally just started with Linux based operating systems so cant help much but when i was installing, my computer wouldn't finish the install so I tried the [alternative install CD](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso) (or if you dont trust a direct link go to [this page](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/precise/) and scroll down to alternative install) and it worked fine :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that. I can't get the computer to start at all now so perhaps an alternative is just what I need.